# How to add sticky components in react native maps?

Tags: google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

I am implementing a Google Map on react native and I would like to know how to add a sticky component on top of it. I googled around, but I didn't get any clear directions. Any help is appreciated guys.

Comment: Can you add your map code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you want to position views absolutely over the top of your MapView.

To have views appear over the top of a view they must come at the end of the returned view. They must also be positioned absolutely.

In this small example the View with `styles.box` is absolutely positioned over the top of the map.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants, MapView } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <MapView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
        />
        <View style={styles.box} /> // <- this view is absolutely positioned above the MapView
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  box: {
    position:'absolute', 
    bottom: 100, 
    width: 200, 
    height: 50 , 
    alignSelf: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  }
});
```

This is what the above code renders. You can try it here in this snack https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/absolutely-positioned-view-over-mapview

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed.